# PHP/MYSQL Join and distinct multiple tables and show results by 2 criteria

Tags: php, mysql, join, distinct, criteria

I have searched around for an issue like I have but I have not found anything :-( , so, I have decided to open a question. I'm working on a travel agency website and I'm stuck. I have 6 tables:

`1. category
 2. country
 3. city
 4. type
 5. offer
 6. price`

Now, the relations of each one is like this: in `offer` table are recorded id's of `category`, `country`, `city`, `type` and, in `price` table is recorded `offer` id. In this way, via admin panel, the process starts by creating a new offer and after that, creating prices for that offer. This is way the offer id is recorded in price table and not inverse.

What I have right now is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  price.prFood,
  offer.* 
FROM
  category,
  country,
  city,
  `type`,
  price 
  INNER JOIN offer 
    ON price.prOfferID = offer.offerID 
WHERE offerType = typeID 
  AND categoryID = offerCategory 
  AND countryID = offerCountry 
  AND prOfferID = offerID 
  AND offerActive = '1' 
  AND offerCity = cityID ;
```

This query shows correctly, only once, every offer that has a price but, what I need is to show also offers that are active and don't have a price. So, I need a little help on the correct query to **show all offers that are active, have or don't have a price**.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join for your price table and move where condition in on clause. I have used aliases to give short names to table, so if I have not selected proper columns, please use right aliases for the columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  p.prFood,
  o.* 
FROM
offer o
LEFT JOIN price p ON  o.offerID = p.prOfferID 
INNER JOIN  category ca ON o.offerCategory = ca.categoryID
INNER JOIN  country c ON o.offerCountry = c.countryID 
INNER JOIN  city ci ON o.offerCity = ci.cityID 
INNER JOIN `type` t ON o.offerType = t.typeID 
AND o.offerActive = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just tried it but it just says that is no offer active :-( I don't know what i'm doing wring but i'll re-check it and reply again.

Comment: @MKhalid, please use upper case 'I' for referring to yourself. I normally just fix these silently, but you have a lot of questions that might need editing `:)`.

Comment: @Oldi can your provide sample data set of your tables [*@sql fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I'll put in a txt and sen the link. Thanks

Comment: @Oldi no not here in comment box :) either edit your question and add sample data set there with table definition or on [*`sqlfiddle.com`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and provide me the link of that fiddle

Comment: I have uploaded at wetransfer with some comments. You can get it here, please [link]https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/1204d7217ed3e6134f61d02b13f5854020140907174808/198ebc37974dfc38946e96ebc586bc3b20140907174808/e9bb81

Comment: Any suggestion, please?

Comment: @Oldi can you provide also table definitions like create table .. full structure with sample data set it will be help full the text file only contains data i need table structure too regards

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Your answer was good but i had a problem with table name definitions. Thanks again for your help!